# Add Unirest to Android Studio with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dependency-management, unirest

I know that Unirest might be considered not so good, but I badly need it to use some API.

Since I'm using Gradle, I cannot follow guides about Maven to include it in my Android Studio project and I found only the following:

```
repositories {
        ...
        maven{
            url 'https://raw.github.com/zeeshanejaz/unirest-android/mvn-repo'
        }
    }
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.mashape.unirest:unirest-android:1.0+'
}
```

However the result is the following:

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

I don't know if it can cause problems, so please, can someone explain me how to include Unirest in my Android Studio project step by step? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had this same problem, found a solution:

Instead of adding:

```
maven{
    url 'https://raw.github.com/zeeshanejaz/unirest-android/mvn-repo'
}
```

to:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

add it to:

```
allprojects {
    ...
    repositories {
        >HERE<
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That repo is locked and hasn't been touched in 6+ years.  Is it REALLY still the correct/canonical way to do Unirest on Android?